# how to implement openfile with .xml extension in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular6

when I clicked on a button it should open the file and it has to accept only .xml files. but I am not having any idea about that in angular. I have done an example in HTML but it just opening all types of files. I need help in .xml extension files

Comment: `<input type="file" accept=".xml">`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `accept` attribute to limit the file type for input.

```
<input type="file" accept=".xml">
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/file

> Acceptable file types can be specified with the accept attribute, which takes a comma-separated list of allowed file extensions or MIME types. Some examples:
>
> - accept="image/png" or accept=".png" — Accepts PNG files.
> - accept="image/png, image/jpeg" or accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" — Accept PNG or JPEG files.
> - accept="image/*" — Accept any file with an image/* MIME type. (Many mobile devices also let the user take a picture with the camera when
>     this is used.)
> - accept=".doc,.docx,.xml,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
>     — accept anything that smells like an MS Word document.